# Why does the scalp hair become grey first?

Tags: human-biology, hair, melanin

I understand that when the hair follicles produce less melanin or stop producing melanin altogether, hair becomes grey. But it seems like it is the scalp hair that becomes grey first. If follicles are producing less and less melanin, shouldn't the hair everywhere become gradually grey? Why is it that the scalp hair greys first?

Comment: Did you do any searching for an answer? What did you find? Please share, as per our guidelines on showing your research. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't do much research for an answer. Prior to posting the question, all I read was an article (https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/004005.htm) that didn't explain it other than saying that it is usually the scalp hair that becomes grey first. Will research more. Should have researched more.  Thanks.

Comment: The answer is right in the article: "Graying is largely determined by your genes." Scalp hair is genetically programmed to go grey first *if* a person's hair will go grey.

Comment: What do you mean "scalp hair"? The hair on top of the head? As far as I know, it's the temple hair (above the ears) that usually go gray first. But in different people the exact place may differ, I've seen right above the forehead, as I've seen the beard too.

Comment: From my own observation, it's usually the chin & jaw that goes gray first, not the scalp.

Comment: @anongoodnurse "Determined by your genes" doesn't come anywhere close to providing an answer about a mechanism. Presumably the "genes" are the same in all parts of the skin.

Comment: @BryanKrause - why would you think that regulation of hair on the scalp and hair on the mons pubis are exactly alike? Skin cells have the same genes; some skin is thick, some is thin (and it's not solely due to use.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse I don't think all hairs are identical, just that all of the cells *have* the same genes - that isn't the same as expression. Saying "it is because of different expression of gene XYZ" is a good mechanism answer. Saying something "is determined by your genes" suggests you are talking about differences between individuals, which is not what the question is about.

Comment: @BryanKrause - A kinda fine line which I accept. Thanks.